# Apache2 mod_rewrite and .htaccess - HTTP_HOST not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write a basic rewrite rule on my VPS to strip the www from the beginning of the hostname:

> RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

It is not working. In fact, if I put an exclamation mark in front of the pattern, it matches... then goes into a redirect loop! What am I missing here? Do I need to add/remove example.com as a server alias?

Comment: I'm being a retard. Should be %{HTTP_HOST}. It's been a long day...

This is now solved.

Answer (score 1):

More generic solution without the need to hardcode the domain into it. Might be usefull, even though you got yours to work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=302,L,QSA]
```